Выводит ошибку в работающем коде (задача с Codeforcers)
Есть задача. Пишет, что ошибка в тесте 7. Всё, что возможно, проверил, все условия выполнены.
Так как обсуждения с решением на сайте нет, только две фразы (just sort. notice 0), решил написать сюда.
Просто не придумать проверочного случая, который приведёт к неправильному ответу.
Вот код:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int n,k,c=0;
    cin >> n >> k;
    k--;
    int scores[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> scores[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < n;j++)
    {
        if((scores[j] >= scores[k]) && (scores[k] > 0))
            c++;   
    }
    cout << c;
    return 0;
}


Исходя из задания, условие в цикле должено иметь вид
for(int j = 0; j < n;j++)
{
    if((scores[j] > 0) && (scores[j] >= scores[k]))
        c++;   
}


Заработало, хотя условие странно составлено: не особо понятно к чему относится "строго положителен" к "k" или к "j"

Ну, если заработало, ответ можно принимать :)

@ИвановЛеонид В английском тексте различается contestant и k-th place finisher,  as long as the contestant earns a positive score

Держите ✅ от меня :)
